# Store credit card details

Tags: commerce

I've built website using drupal 7. Site is having store of products, for transactions using commerce, commerce_payflow_pro modules.
Requirement:
Store -> Orders table not containing used credit card details i.e. last 4 digit of credit card number, used to place transaction & card type used to place the transaction.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce Card on File](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile) module was built exactly to solve this purpose!

> Commerce Card on File provides an API and user interface for storing and reusing credit card data on subsequent orders within Drupal Commerce. The module does not retain full card numbers locally but instead stores the remote ID of the full card data from the payment gateway used to validate and process your credit card transactions. This means card on file data will only be good for a single payment gateway; if you change payment gateways or accounts, your stored card data may no longer be usable.

Comment: Commerce card on file module not supporting commerce payflow pro gateway

Comment: Suggest some alternative approach